# Hide a whole tab using SwitcherConfig in Magento Ui Form

Tags: magento-2.3, uicomponents

I have used two different dynamicRows component in my custom form using Modifier Pool. Now I have to hide/show these two components based on a checkbox. I have used switcherConfig to hide fields. But the same is not working for dynamicRows.

```
'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                  'switcherConfig' => [
                        'rules' => [
                            "0" => [
                                "value" => 0,
                                "actions" => [
                                    "0" => [
                                        "target" => "form.form.fieldset.field",
                                        "callback" => "hide"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ],
                            "1" => [
                                "value" => 1,
                                "actions" => [
                                    "0" => [
                                        "target" => "form.form.fieldset.field",
                                        "callback" => "show"
                                    ],
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        'enabled' => true
                    ]
              ]
    ]
```